# Genymotion, не вводится текст в EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, genymotion

Имеется вот такое поле ввода, с помощью танцев с бубном заставил появляться клавиатуру в Genymotion,
но при этом все ровно ничего не вводится, разве что из буфера обмена получается вставить.
Даже назначил OnClick на это поле, событие в логе видно (Log.d(TAG, "editName.OnClick");).Virtual keyboard в настройках включена, Hardware Physical keyboard в настройках не нашел.

[Видео с экрана](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dWuRhdm4Bn8)

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/catlist"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editID"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:hint="@string/Name"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:editable="true">
</EditText>

editName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                editName.requestFocus();

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                //imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
                //imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editName.getWindowToken(), 0);

                Log.d(TAG, "editName.OnClick");
            }
        });
```

Comment: А на каком языке пытались вводить текст, если на русском - то попробуйте на английском...

Comment: это не с EditText'ом проблема, а с Genymotion.

Comment: И на английском и цифры. В общем проблема решена.
Смена эмулятора на Nox ничего не меняла.

android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"